# Can one reminiscence comprise many items?

Tags: nouns, countability

Can a reminiscence hold many items? Example sentence:

> A reminiscence I'll never forget **are** the days I started noticing her.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Verbs, including copulas, agree with their subjects, not their objects. ***A*** reminiscence **is** ...

However—

2. We don't use *reminiscence* in the sense you appear to intend.

   A *reminiscence* is an **act** of remembering (or perhaps even more often an act of narrating), not the object of the act, the thing or matter which is remembered.

   It is acceptable to speak of the object as a *memory*, but properly it is a *memory **of** [the object]*.

   > A memory I will always cherish is that of the days . . .

   But in the presence of *forget*, either *reminiscence* or *memory* is pretty much piling on redundancy. It's much simpler and more natural to say

   > I will never forget the days . . .

Comment: So, OP's sentence is basically saying that he'll never forget the time he sat around remembering the days he started noticing her. Which, I'm guessing, is probably not what he intended to say.